# Describe distribution measure probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

So we will consider the probability space (discrete case) where $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,...\}$. We also have $T(\{n\})=(1-x)x^n$, where $T$ denotes the probability measure and where $x$ is a fixed number for $x\in (0,1)$. Now let $\lambda:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a R.V. such that

\begin{equation}
\lambda(n)=\text{the remainder from division of }n \text{ by } 3
\end{equation}
a) Describe the distribution measure of $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I know the remainders will be 0,1 and 2 and it continues like that, but I don't see how to proceed further.

Comment: $P(\text{remainder = }0)=T(0)+T(3)+T(6)+\dots$. Substitute the formula for $T(n)$. You will get an infinite sum, which is a geometric series, so you can evaluate it using the infinite geometric series formula. Then, do the same for $P(\text{remainder = }1)=T(1)+T(4)+T(7)+...$ and $P(\text{remainder = }2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not leave the question unanswered. As by the comment by Mike Earnest:
$$\mathbb{P}_\lambda(3\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{P}(\lambda \in 3\mathbb N)=\mathbb{P}(\cup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\lambda =3k)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{P}(\lambda=3k)=\sum_k (1-x)x^{3k}$$
Similarly  for $\mathbb{3\mathbb N+1}$ and $3\mathbb{N}+2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. One question, the last part of your equation is not clear for me. How can you get from $\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}}(1-x)(x)^{3k}$ to $\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}(x^3)^{k}+\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}(-x^4)^{k}$ I think it should be $\sum_{k\in \mathbb N}(x^3)^{k}-x\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}(x^3)^{k}$ or do you have additional comment on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x\cdot (x^3)^k=x^1\cdot x^{3k}=x^{3k+1}\neq (x^{4})^k$